# Linker error with Unity (C unit testing framework)

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmake, unity-test-framework

I've littered through Stackoverflow trying to get Unity unit test framework (https://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity) linked and built on CMAKE so that I can write unit tests but I keep hitting this same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_setUp", referenced from:
      _UnityDefaultTestRun in libunity.a(unity.c.o)
  "_tearDown", referenced from:
      _UnityDefaultTestRun in libunity.a(unity.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/test_problem2_59.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/test_problem2_59.exe.dir/al
```

I have documented my final attempt here https://github.com/aamarin/computer_systems/tree/dev with the latest commit being the unstable commit.  I'm not sure what else I'm missing in computer_systems/tests/CMakeLists.txt to get this working.  Just looking for some guidance and maybe an explanation I might be missing from here https://gitlab.com/CLIUtils/modern-cmake/-/blob/master/examples/extended-project/src/CMakeLists.txt.  Guidance on better structuring my folder structure is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add empty functions named `setUp` and `teadDown`. [UnityGettingStartedGuide](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity/blob/master/docs/UnityGettingStartedGuide.md).